# Disable fullscreen mode on a uncooperative window

Tags: xorg, window-manager, fullscreen

I have a program that opens in fullscreen mode. It doesn't provide any way to fix this within the program, and `wmctrl -b remove,fullscreen` has no effect. (Nor does the equivalent `xprop` command.)

Answer (score 0):

*.Create a desktop shortcut for the program

*.Go to properties of the shortcut

*.Click on the "shortcut" tab

*.Under "Run", select "minimized" or "normal window."

Comment: ... <sarcasm>Whats a desktop shortcut?</sarcasm> (I'm using a operating system, not some overgrown window manager out of Redmond.) (ETA: and that doesnt even work on windows: see 'uncooperative')